# lmer: predictions on population level trigger an error

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I want to use linear mixed model and make predictions on population level (i.e. using only fixed effects and using 0 instead of random effects).

Example model:

```
require(lme4)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
summary(fm1)
# values for prediction:
newx <- seq(min(sleepstudy$Days), max(sleepstudy$Days))
```

I tried several methods of the prediction on population level but they all failed:

```
pred <- predict(fm1, newdata = data.frame(Days = newx), allow.new.levels = TRUE)
# Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor Subject within model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if possible

pred <- predict(fm1, newdata = data.frame(Days = newx, Subject = NA), allow.new.levels = TRUE)
# Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, Subject

pred <- predict(fm1, newdata = data.frame(Days = newx, Subject = as.factor(NA)), allow.new.levels = TRUE)
# Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, Subject
```

I tried to find the manual for the proper prediction method, but I don't know how? I tried to look at `help(package = "lme4")` and the closest function I found was `predict.merMod` (though the class of model `fm1` is `lmerMod` not `merMod`). `?predict.merMod` reads:

> **allow.new.levels**   (logical) if FALSE (default), then any new levels (or NA values) detected in newdata will trigger an error; if
>   TRUE, then the prediction will use the unconditional
>   (population-level) values for data with previously unobserved levels
>   (or NAs)

It specifically says "or NAs", but it apparently doesn't work that way!!

1. Am I looking at the help page of a proper method? If not, what is the right method?
2. How to make the prediction work on the population level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `re.form`:

> re.form: formula for random effects to condition on.  If ‘NULL’,
>             include all random effects; if ‘NA’ or ‘~0’, include no
>             random effects

```
require(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
newx <- seq(min(sleepstudy$Days), max(sleepstudy$Days))
predict(fm1, newdata=data.frame(Days=newx), re.form=NA)
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 251.4051 261.8724 272.3397 282.8070 293.2742 303.7415 314.2088 324.6761 
##        9       10 
## 335.1434 345.6107
```

As for your other questions:

- `merMod` is a "super-class" that includes both linear (`lmerMod`) and generalized linear (`glmerMod`) models: see `?"merMod-class"`
- your second two tries probably *should* have worked; however, `allow.new.levels` was designed for cases with occasional `NA` values, not all `NA` values ... `predict(fm1, newdata = data.frame(Days = newx, Subject = "a"), allow.new.levels = TRUE)` does work.  It looks like the code detects an all-`NA` column and interprets it as something having gone wrong upstream - this could be fixed in the code, but doesn't seem very high-priority since `re.form` exists.

Comment: Thanks Ben! It's probably the wording in the help that confused me: "... to condition on.". I am not a native speaker, please what that means? Probably that's just some english wording of certain situation with the random effects? Or is it that there is some "condition" concept in lmer or the statistic itself? I had no idea what this means so I probably overlooked it.

Comment: it's statistical terminology (jargon): "conditioning on" something means taking its value into account when predicting.